# How to run VBoxManage.exe?

Tags: virtualbox

The file is located in `Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe` and is used as a command-line interface with VirtualBox.

I'm using it to convert the .vdi image to a .vdmk (for VMware).

http://scottlinux.com/2011/06/24/convert-vdi-to-vmdk-virtualbox-to-vmware/

Here's an example script:

```
$ VBoxManage list hdds
```

But where do I run this command? In Windows cmd? I tried both in cmd and in Linux but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What is the error message you see ?

Comment: cmd.exe worked, I just had to navigate to the VirtualBox folder, I couldn't run the program from root.

Comment: You need to add the VirtualBox installation folder (i.e. default: `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`) to the `advanced system settings > system properties > system environment variables` to be able to run this command from cmd or powershell

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a pretty sure bet that running an exe file in Linux won't work. In Windows you do run it from the command prompt. If you get a message about the command not being found then either add the path to the command to your PATH environment variable or specify the full path to the command.

If the command runs but it's not doing what you think it should be doing then read the documentation.

Answer (score 88):

You need to either use the whole path for the command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" list hdds
```

Or `cd` to the `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` directory, then:

```
VBoxManage.exe list hdds
```

Or you can add add the `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` directory to your `PATH`:

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
```

and then you can run `VBoxManage` from anywhere

Comment: ...or you create a `vboxmanage.bat` “stub“, somewhere in your path (e.g. I collect those in `d:\scripts`) to avoid polluting your path to endless lengths... Content: `@CALL "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage.exe" %*`

Comment: @FrankNocke you could use mklink for a similar purpose

Comment: To do the first option, put an amperstand before the full path, like `& "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" list hdds`

Answer (score 2):

1. From the Windows7 start menu go to search programs and files folder.
2. Type in CMD. Do not press enter.
3. Right Click on the CMD icon and select copy.
4. Navigate to c:\"Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
5. Right click in the window and select paste.

You should now be able to use VboxManage from the CMD window.
Try typing in VboxManage /?
If you see the help list then your on your way.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Windows but this *smells* like a bad idea.  Surely there's a better way to change your working directory on the Windows command line.

Comment: @Ladadadada agreed that "cd" should be the normal way, but in case of long path names i need to travel where i have already an explorer window open for that path, i tend to use this (copy/paste path) approach as well